# Comparing SQL results with Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, sqlite

I was looking for a way to my program to take 2 values from my database, compare them and update or insert some value.
I tried in sqlite3 but I didn't find a good solution and I tried on python, but when I run the program, the values are different and never match. I already look on google, here on stack overflow, but didn't find anything.

```
cursor.execute("select * from [Sistema]")
Teste = cursor.fetchall()
cursor.execute("select [SistemaOperacional] from [Sistema] where [SistemaOperacional] = 'teste'")
comparacao = cursor.fetchall()
testando = comparacao
for row in Teste:
    #I was checking the values to see if they where equal
    print(comparação[0]) #Value ('teste',)
    print(row[0]) #Value 'teste'
    if row[0] == comparação[0]:
        cursor.execute("Update [Sistema] set [SistemaOperacional] = '1' where [VersaoBanco] = 3")
        print('Executado')
        break
    else:
        cursor.execute("insert into [Sistema] values ('9','9','1')")
        print('não')
        break
```

the output whas

```
('teste',)
teste
não
```

I wasn't finding a solution for this in sql, that's why I tried with python, but I'm open to listen any other suggestion than python

Comment: Please give us an example of a short input, what output you get, and what output you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could be on the wrong track here, but isn't your `comparação[0]` itself a tuple, so you probably want to be comparing `comparação[0][0]` with `row[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

It's a pretty common problem for people unfamiliar with Python/MySQL to run into troubles receiving tuples back from querying. `comparacao[0]` is a **tuple**. Tuples are compared lexicographically **by element**, so you'd have to retrieve the first element (like @Gwyn Evans said) e.g. `comparação[0][0]` in order to compare it to your string `row`.

Here is a link to Python docs about comparisons: https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/comparisons.html

Comment: Thanks, this doc is helping me a lot, I was thinking about other situations, this will clarify a lot :)

Comment: no problem!!! always glad to help :) python is truly awesome